# pyOpenSSL on Windows 7 Crypto error

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyopenssl

Ok, I've attempted to make pyopenssl work on my windows 7 x64 instance and can't be very much luck.

I want to use pyopenSSL and I've installed like this pip install pyopenSSL.

Matter is I can't make it run, Installed python 2.7 added to register, make pywin32  for it, but can't work. I have all necessary config in PATH and scripts, but doesn't work at all.

When I tried here's the log I get.

What am I missing here? I'm blind. Thanks in advance for any help.

```
------------------------------------------------------------
C:\sdks\Python27\Scripts\pip-script.py run on 08/05/13 00:37:15
Downloading/unpacking pyopenssl

  Getting page https://pypi.python.org/simple/pyopenssl/
  URLs to search for versions for pyopenssl:
  * https://pypi.python.org/simple/pyopenssl/
  Analyzing links from page https://pypi.python.org/simple/pyOpenSSL/
    Skipping link https://pypi.python.org/packages/2.4/p/pyOpenSSL/pyOpenSSL-0.13.winxp32-py2.4.exe#md5=8ae7625797c7c9a9faf76499c0ad5061 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/pyOpenSSL/); unknown archive format: .exe
    Skipping link https://pypi.python.org/packages/2.4/p/pyOpenSSL/pyOpenSSL-0.13-py2.4-win32.egg#md5=8695c7c3d19ff6d6fb8d4d6071a880fc (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/pyOpenSSL/); unknown archive format: .egg
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/p/pyOpenSSL/pyOpenSSL-0.6.tar.gz#md5=af67fda6d2125cae9c56ee50430a40c7 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/pyOpenSSL/), version: 0.6
    Skipping link https://pypi.python.org/packages/2.7/p/pyOpenSSL/pyOpenSSL-0.12.winxp32-py2.7.msi#md5=727f31a727cb29302d7618bf2bcb8af3 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/pyOpenSSL/); unknown archive format: .msi
    Skipping link https://pypi.python.org/packages/2.4/p/pyOpenSSL/pyOpenSSL-0.10.winxp32-py2.4.exe#md5=a808b0e53d31aea0158ef56f8fc0af4b (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/pyOpenSSL/); unknown archive format: .exe
    Skipping link https://pypi.python.org/packages/2.7/p/pyOpenSSL/pyOpenSSL-0.12-py2.7-win32.egg#md5=c343e3833b725e060c094bbf33349349 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/pyOpenSSL/); unknown archive format: .egg
    Skipping link https://pypi.python.org/packages/3.2/p/pyOpenSSL/pyOpenSSL-0.12.winxp32-py3.2.msi#md5=a64f1513926c994b44e9922e56c47a84 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/pyOpenSSL/); unknown archive format: .msi
    Skipping link https://pypi.python.org/packages/2.5/p/pyOpenSSL/pyOpenSSL-0.13.winxp32-py2.5.exe#md5=b61ef0e38b6313277ca6b9c738700641 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/pyOpenSSL/); unknown archive format: .exe
    Skipping link https://pypi.python.org/packages/2.6/p/pyOpenSSL/pyOpenSSL-0.10-py2.6-win32.egg#md5=b480ef0b4b26d6493b62994f4c2903db (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/pyOpenSSL/); unknown archive format: .egg
    Skipping link https://pypi.python.org/packages/3.2/p/pyOpenSSL/pyOpenSSL-0.13-py3.2-win32.egg#md5=8c21807ad495d6bdd4a729f21cc8c164 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/pyOpenSSL/); unknown archive format: .egg
    Skipping link https://pypi.python.org/packages/2.5/p/pyOpenSSL/pyOpenSSL-0.10-py2.5-win32.egg#md5=00ddbd942655468a0f6d1e9947ec05a4 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/pyOpenSSL/); unknown archive format: .egg
    Skipping link https://pypi.python.org/packages/2.6/p/pyOpenSSL/pyOpenSSL-0.9.win32-py2.6.exe#md5=f5f39048dd5f05375f9a8198fe993fcc (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/pyOpenSSL/); unknown archive format: .exe
    Skipping link https://pypi.python.org/packages/2.5/p/pyOpenSSL/pyOpenSSL-0.13-py2.5-win32.egg#md5=9f251206280201e7837c51e15c32a4e5 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/pyOpenSSL/); unknown archive format: .egg
    Skipping link https://pypi.python.org/packages/2.4/p/pyOpenSSL/pyOpenSSL-0.12-py2.4-win32.egg#md5=4cb0d30f99b3d3e72996dba820f1cad0 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/pyOpenSSL/); unknown archive format: .egg
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/p/pyOpenSSL/pyOpenSSL-0.7.tar.gz#md5=1924edc58c1e99f27763971d9959ea15 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/pyOpenSSL/), version: 0.7
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/p/pyOpenSSL/pyOpenSSL-0.9.tar.gz#md5=5bf282b2d6a03af921920c34079580f2 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/pyOpenSSL/), version: 0.9
    Skipping link https://pypi.python.org/packages/2.6/p/pyOpenSSL/pyOpenSSL-0.12.winxp32-py2.6.msi#md5=9ff89287d92462d7ad1b4638746110be (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/pyOpenSSL/); unknown archive format: .msi
    Skipping link https://pypi.python.org/packages/2.6/p/pyOpenSSL/pyOpenSSL-0.12-py2.6-win32.egg#md5=e006a26f085cf6399eee86b6485eaa6d (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/pyOpenSSL/); unknown archive format: .egg
    Skipping link https://pypi.python.org/packages/2.5/p/pyOpenSSL/pyOpenSSL-0.10.winxp32-py2.5.exe#md5=2e6148d48dd9864ebdac2c94b36ea9d7 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/pyOpenSSL/); unknown archive format: .exe
    Skipping link https://pypi.python.org/packages/2.6/p/pyOpenSSL/pyOpenSSL-0.12-py2.6-win-amd64.egg#md5=8797b1f77437405ec2173f3646160a47 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/pyOpenSSL/); unknown archive format: .egg
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/p/pyOpenSSL/pyOpenSSL-0.8.tar.gz#md5=c1d86fdeb0cfd33dd42aa243c6a41f5e (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/pyOpenSSL/), version: 0.8
    Skipping link https://pypi.python.org/packages/2.6/p/pyOpenSSL/pyOpenSSL-0.10.winxp32-py2.6.exe#md5=54c7dd629bf4004569a7c97c9ef6daa5 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/pyOpenSSL/); unknown archive format: .exe
    Skipping link https://pypi.python.org/packages/2.7/p/pyOpenSSL/pyOpenSSL-0.13.winxp32-py2.7.msi#md5=3438c0e3a87060959d7061f939c6b03d (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/pyOpenSSL/); unknown archive format: .msi
    Skipping link https://pypi.python.org/packages/2.5/p/pyOpenSSL/pyOpenSSL-0.12.winxp32-py2.5.msi#md5=a340bec6c4d1cd8a80f56ce6cdfbe5d2 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/pyOpenSSL/); unknown archive format: .msi
    Skipping link https://pypi.python.org/packages/2.4/p/pyOpenSSL/pyOpenSSL-0.10-py2.4-win32.egg#md5=c12159efa233333541140c24e1fa094b (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/pyOpenSSL/); unknown archive format: .egg
    Skipping link https://pypi.python.org/packages/3.2/p/pyOpenSSL/pyOpenSSL-0.12-py3.2-win32.egg#md5=7f0777a02614f729d8ef9627995d2705 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/pyOpenSSL/); unknown archive format: .egg
    Skipping link https://pypi.python.org/packages/2.6/p/pyOpenSSL/pyOpenSSL-0.10.winxp32-py2.6.msi#md5=90920217fb35d76524cab66c8c135cc8 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/pyOpenSSL/); unknown archive format: .msi
    Skipping link https://pypi.python.org/packages/2.5/p/pyOpenSSL/pyOpenSSL-0.12-py2.5-win32.egg#md5=45d679ed7d386f48d1d5dd1bc8e539cb (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/pyOpenSSL/); unknown archive format: .egg
    Skipping link https://pypi.python.org/packages/2.6/p/pyOpenSSL/pyOpenSSL-0.13.winxp32-py2.6.msi#md5=1646faad52bcbdb56c81435a51e99bf5 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/pyOpenSSL/); unknown archive format: .msi
    Skipping link https://pypi.python.org/packages/2.5/p/pyOpenSSL/pyOpenSSL-0.10.winxp32-py2.5.msi#md5=b7cf3e16a675937543243bef3ad3c106 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/pyOpenSSL/); unknown archive format: .msi
    Skipping link https://pypi.python.org/packages/3.2/p/pyOpenSSL/pyOpenSSL-0.13.winxp32-py3.2.exe#md5=2bb725ce9ea21ccac9999d614aac2499 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/pyOpenSSL/); unknown archive format: .exe
    Skipping link https://pypi.python.org/packages/2.6/p/pyOpenSSL/pyOpenSSL-0.13.winxp32-py2.6.exe#md5=8935156097d9396161063fba5eb7f4a5 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/pyOpenSSL/); unknown archive format: .exe
    Skipping link https://pypi.python.org/packages/2.6/p/pyOpenSSL/pyOpenSSL-0.13-py2.6-win32.egg#md5=939c493e3415da166918bc86c40a945b (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/pyOpenSSL/); unknown archive format: .egg
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/p/pyOpenSSL/pyOpenSSL-0.10.tar.gz#md5=34db8056ec53ce80c7f5fc58bee9f093 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/pyOpenSSL/), version: 0.10
    Skipping link https://pypi.python.org/packages/2.7/p/pyOpenSSL/pyOpenSSL-0.13-py2.7-win32.egg#md5=e0b7b0d2cccca83ae38e11c3a105dfe4 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/pyOpenSSL/); unknown archive format: .egg
    Skipping link https://pypi.python.org/packages/2.5/p/pyOpenSSL/pyOpenSSL-0.13.winxp32-py2.5.msi#md5=6c24249c2dc772e4bb60bbb3a139eba8 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/pyOpenSSL/); unknown archive format: .msi
    Skipping link https://pypi.python.org/packages/2.7/p/pyOpenSSL/pyOpenSSL-0.13.winxp32-py2.7.exe#md5=3acf96ea5ed7aec880570cc6477f8507 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/pyOpenSSL/); unknown archive format: .exe
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/p/pyOpenSSL/pyOpenSSL-0.12.tar.gz#md5=60a7bbb6160950823eddcbba2cbcb0d6 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/pyOpenSSL/), version: 0.12
    Skipping link https://pypi.python.org/packages/3.2/p/pyOpenSSL/pyOpenSSL-0.13.winxp32-py3.2.msi#md5=2e8e10ecfcf1f007ce2503839a3a2e30 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/pyOpenSSL/); unknown archive format: .msi
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/p/pyOpenSSL/pyOpenSSL-0.13.tar.gz#md5=767bca18a71178ca353dff9e10941929 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/pyOpenSSL/), version: 0.13
    Found link https://launchpadlibrarian.net/58498441/pyOpenSSL-0.11.tar.gz#md5=9e76e57e00fa48745fcfe23944db1e6c (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/pyOpenSSL/), version: 0.11
  Using version 0.13 (newest of versions: 0.13, 0.12, 0.11, 0.10, 0.9, 0.8, 0.7, 0.6)
  Downloading from URL https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/p/pyOpenSSL/pyOpenSSL-0.13.tar.gz#md5=767bca18a71178ca353dff9e10941929 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/pyOpenSSL/)
  Running setup.py egg_info for package pyopenssl

    running egg_info
    creating pip-egg-info\pyOpenSSL.egg-info
    writing pip-egg-info\pyOpenSSL.egg-info\PKG-INFO
    writing top-level names to pip-egg-info\pyOpenSSL.egg-info\top_level.txt
    writing dependency_links to pip-egg-info\pyOpenSSL.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
    writing manifest file 'pip-egg-info\pyOpenSSL.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
    warning: manifest_maker: standard file '-c' not found


    reading manifest file 'pip-egg-info\pyOpenSSL.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
    reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found anywhere in distribution

    writing manifest file 'pip-egg-info\pyOpenSSL.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
  Source in c:\users\igorco~1\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-igor costa\pyopenssl has version 0.13, which satisfies requirement pyopenssl
Installing collected packages: pyopenssl

  Running setup.py install for pyopenssl

    Running command C:\sdks\Python27\python.exe -c "import setuptools;__file__='c:\\users\\igorco~1\\appdata\\local\\temp\\pip-build-Igor Costa\\pyopenssl\\setup.py';exec(compile(open(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record c:\users\igorco~1\appdata\local\temp\pip-rwp7c6-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-2.7
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\OpenSSL
    copying OpenSSL\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\OpenSSL
    copying OpenSSL\tsafe.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\OpenSSL
    copying OpenSSL\version.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\OpenSSL
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\OpenSSL\test
    copying OpenSSL\test\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\OpenSSL\test
    copying OpenSSL\test\util.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\OpenSSL\test
    copying OpenSSL\test\test_crypto.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\OpenSSL\test
    copying OpenSSL\test\test_rand.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\OpenSSL\test
    copying OpenSSL\test\test_ssl.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\OpenSSL\test
    running build_ext
    building 'OpenSSL.crypto' extension

    Traceback (most recent call last):

      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>

      File "c:\users\igorco~1\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-Igor Costa\pyopenssl\setup.py", line 221, in <module>

        ...  and much more ;)"""

      File "C:\sdks\Python27\lib\distutils\core.py", line 152, in setup

        dist.run_commands()

      File "C:\sdks\Python27\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 953, in run_commands

        self.run_command(cmd)

      File "C:\sdks\Python27\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 972, in run_command

        cmd_obj.run()

      File "C:\sdks\Python27\lib\site-packages\distribute-0.6.49-py2.7.egg\setuptools\command\install.py", line 53, in run

        return _install.run(self)

      File "C:\sdks\Python27\lib\distutils\command\install.py", line 563, in run

        self.run_command('build')

      File "C:\sdks\Python27\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 326, in run_command

        self.distribution.run_command(command)

      File "C:\sdks\Python27\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 972, in run_command

        cmd_obj.run()

      File "C:\sdks\Python27\lib\distutils\command\build.py", line 127, in run

        self.run_command(cmd_name)

      File "C:\sdks\Python27\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 326, in run_command

        self.distribution.run_command(command)

      File "C:\sdks\Python27\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 972, in run_command

        cmd_obj.run()

      File "c:\users\igorco~1\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-Igor Costa\pyopenssl\setup.py", line 166, in run

        build_ext.run(self)

      File "C:\sdks\Python27\lib\distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 339, in run

        self.build_extensions()

      File "C:\sdks\Python27\lib\distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 448, in build_extensions

        self.build_extension(ext)

      File "C:\sdks\Python27\lib\distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 498, in build_extension

        depends=ext.depends)

      File "C:\sdks\Python27\lib\distutils\msvc9compiler.py", line 473, in compile

        self.initialize()

      File "C:\sdks\Python27\lib\distutils\msvc9compiler.py", line 383, in initialize

        vc_env = query_vcvarsall(VERSION, plat_spec)

      File "C:\sdks\Python27\lib\distutils\msvc9compiler.py", line 299, in query_vcvarsall

        raise ValueError(str(list(result.keys())))

    ValueError: [u'path']

    Complete output from command C:\sdks\Python27\python.exe -c "import setuptools;__file__='c:\\users\\igorco~1\\appdata\\local\\temp\\pip-build-Igor Costa\\pyopenssl\\setup.py';exec(compile(open(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record c:\users\igorco~1\appdata\local\temp\pip-rwp7c6-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed:

    running install

running build

running build_py

creating build

creating build\lib.win-amd64-2.7

creating build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\OpenSSL

copying OpenSSL\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\OpenSSL

copying OpenSSL\tsafe.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\OpenSSL

copying OpenSSL\version.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\OpenSSL

creating build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\OpenSSL\test

copying OpenSSL\test\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\OpenSSL\test

copying OpenSSL\test\util.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\OpenSSL\test

copying OpenSSL\test\test_crypto.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\OpenSSL\test

copying OpenSSL\test\test_rand.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\OpenSSL\test

copying OpenSSL\test\test_ssl.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\OpenSSL\test

running build_ext

building 'OpenSSL.crypto' extension

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>

  File "c:\users\igorco~1\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-Igor Costa\pyopenssl\setup.py", line 221, in <module>

    ...  and much more ;)"""

  File "C:\sdks\Python27\lib\distutils\core.py", line 152, in setup

    dist.run_commands()

  File "C:\sdks\Python27\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 953, in run_commands

    self.run_command(cmd)

  File "C:\sdks\Python27\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 972, in run_command

    cmd_obj.run()

  File "C:\sdks\Python27\lib\site-packages\distribute-0.6.49-py2.7.egg\setuptools\command\install.py", line 53, in run

    return _install.run(self)

  File "C:\sdks\Python27\lib\distutils\command\install.py", line 563, in run

    self.run_command('build')

  File "C:\sdks\Python27\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 326, in run_command

    self.distribution.run_command(command)

  File "C:\sdks\Python27\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 972, in run_command

    cmd_obj.run()

  File "C:\sdks\Python27\lib\distutils\command\build.py", line 127, in run

    self.run_command(cmd_name)

  File "C:\sdks\Python27\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 326, in run_command

    self.distribution.run_command(command)

  File "C:\sdks\Python27\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 972, in run_command

    cmd_obj.run()

  File "c:\users\igorco~1\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-Igor Costa\pyopenssl\setup.py", line 166, in run

    build_ext.run(self)

  File "C:\sdks\Python27\lib\distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 339, in run

    self.build_extensions()

  File "C:\sdks\Python27\lib\distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 448, in build_extensions

    self.build_extension(ext)

  File "C:\sdks\Python27\lib\distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 498, in build_extension

    depends=ext.depends)

  File "C:\sdks\Python27\lib\distutils\msvc9compiler.py", line 473, in compile

    self.initialize()

  File "C:\sdks\Python27\lib\distutils\msvc9compiler.py", line 383, in initialize

    vc_env = query_vcvarsall(VERSION, plat_spec)

  File "C:\sdks\Python27\lib\distutils\msvc9compiler.py", line 299, in query_vcvarsall

    raise ValueError(str(list(result.keys())))

ValueError: [u'path']

----------------------------------------

Cleaning up...

  Removing temporary dir c:\users\igorco~1\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-Igor Costa...
Command C:\sdks\Python27\python.exe -c "import setuptools;__file__='c:\\users\\igorco~1\\appdata\\local\\temp\\pip-build-Igor Costa\\pyopenssl\\setup.py';exec(compile(open(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record c:\users\igorco~1\appdata\local\temp\pip-rwp7c6-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed failed with error code 1 in c:\users\igorco~1\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-Igor Costa\pyopenssl

Exception information:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\sdks\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip-1.4-py2.7.egg\pip\basecommand.py", line 134, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "C:\sdks\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip-1.4-py2.7.egg\pip\commands\install.py", line 241, in run
    requirement_set.install(install_options, global_options, root=options.root_path)
  File "C:\sdks\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip-1.4-py2.7.egg\pip\req.py", line 1277, in install
    requirement.install(install_options, global_options, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\sdks\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip-1.4-py2.7.egg\pip\req.py", line 622, in install
    cwd=self.source_dir, filter_stdout=self._filter_install, show_stdout=False)
  File "C:\sdks\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip-1.4-py2.7.egg\pip\util.py", line 670, in call_subprocess
    % (command_desc, proc.returncode, cwd))
InstallationError: Command C:\sdks\Python27\python.exe -c "import setuptools;__file__='c:\\users\\igorco~1\\appdata\\local\\temp\\pip-build-Igor Costa\\pyopenssl\\setup.py';exec(compile(open(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record c:\users\igorco~1\appdata\local\temp\pip-rwp7c6-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed failed with error code 1 in c:\users\igorco~1\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-Igor Costa\pyopenssl
```

Answer (score 1):

You can download pyOpenSsl built msi [here](https://launchpad.net/pyopenssl)!
If u use 64bit windows, u can just download 32bit built package, and when install, choose the python location manually. 
good luck.